# Selenium automation Mouse over action

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform a mouse-over action. Using ebay.co.uk as a case study, I want to mouse over on the category "Refurbished" represented by the XPath below, but I am getting an error that

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a"}
```

```
driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello in your example you use [7] but on my computer it look like to be [6].

```
//html/body/div[6]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a
```

Otherwise, you could try to use something like that.
It do not use index to select element so I guess it is more reliable if the website change.

```
//div[@id="vl-flyout-nav"]//ul//li//a[contains(text(),'Refurbished')]
```

Hope this answer your question

Answer (score 1):

You can change your XPath expression as below:

```
(//a[text()='Refurbished'])[1]
```

**Refer the working code below:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
// Click on Accept Cookie button
JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
j.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept all']"))));
        
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement refurbished = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[text()='Refurbished'])[1]"));
action.moveToElement(refurbished).perform();
```